# Animating rotation of elements starting at different rotation angles

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to create a simple animation, an element should do a full spin around a radius(using transform-origin), the problem is that I want that element to begin with an angle.

For a spin that starts from 0deg, I know I can do:

```
@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

But I want it to start with an angle, and this doesn't work:

```
@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
}
```

I understand why. because its the same point... but how do i do a full spin in this case?
Here's a simplified version of it. I have no problem with mixing this with JS to make it work:
https://jsfiddle.net/shock/qqdkj7hx/

Comment: I think you should 360 to 45: 100% { transform: rotate(405deg); }

Comment: I meant add 360 to 45

Comment: You are right, I feel a bit stupid, I wasted more time than i should on this

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(405deg); }
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/qqdkj7hx/1/)